# A metric space such that all closed balls are compact is complete.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space that has the property that for any $x\in X$ and $r>0$, the closed ball
>   $$\bar{B}(x,r):=\{y\in X:d(x,y)\leq r\}$$
>   is compact. Show that $X$ is complete.

I think I have a proof, but I am only using that the unit closed balls $\bar{B}(x,1)$ are compact. Maybe I am missing something?

**Attempt:** Let $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a Cauchy sequence in $(X,d)$. Then, $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\geq N$, $d(x_n,x_N)<1$. Thus, $\forall n\geq N$, $x_n\in\bar{B}(x_N,1)$ which is compact by assumption, so $(x_n)_{n=N}^\infty$ is a sequence in this compact set and thus has a convergent subsequence. Hence, $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence that has a convergent subsequence, so it converges in $(X,d)$. Therefore, $(X,d)$ is complete.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Mikie likes.  You have it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your proof is right.

As a justification that it is not strange that you needed a little less than the hypothesis, let me show you what happens when your metric space is a normed space: 
since any two balls are homeomorphic, if one closed ball is compact than all are. Indeed, 
$$
\bar B(0,1)\simeq \bar B(y,r)
$$
via the continuous function $x\mapsto r(x+y)$.

Comment: Note that the Spenser asked about metric spaces in general and that kind of argument doesn't quite work then.

Comment: You are totally right. I seldom use metric spaces which are not normed spaces...

Comment: In time, another justification of why this is not strange might be the fact that every metric space admits a limited and topologically equivalent metric (for example $\tilde{d} = d/(1 + d)$ ), so the whole original space is a limited ball in this new equivalent metric, in the spirit of Neal's remark below.

Answer (score 4):

If there is an $r>0$ with $\overline{B(x,r)}$ compact for all $x$, then for any $r>\varepsilon>0$, $\overline{B(x,\varepsilon)}$ is compact. It's not *so* much stronger that you're just using compactness of $B(x,1)$ for all $x$; that implies compactness at all smaller scales.