# Prove that if any closed ball in $X$ is compact then there exists $y\in F$ such that $d(p,y)=d(p,X)$, for $F$ closed, $p$ a point.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $F$ included in $X$ and closed, p a point in $X-F$.

Prove that if any closed ball in X is compact then there exists y in F such that

$d(p,y)=d(p,F)$.

I have been trying to do it by sequences, but i dont know how to use the hypothesis.

Comment: Isn't $d(p,X)$ going to be zero? Do you mean $d(p,F)$?

Comment: Get us started by showing us your thoughts and what you have tried. Then we will likely chime in to help.

Comment: Your idea with sequences is on the right path. Basically, the distance $d(p,F)$ is the infimum over $x\in F$ of $d(p,x)$. If you know (or can see that $d(p,\cdot)$ is a continuous function, then what can you say about the infimum over a compact set (can you see that $p$ must be in some compact set?)?

Answer (score 2):

Pick some $x\in F$ and let $\alpha=d(p,x)$, then we can restrict our search to $\overline{B_\alpha(p)}\cap F$ (where $B_r(a)$ is the ball of radius $r$ around $a$). This is a compact set as it is a closed subset of a compact set. Now $d(p,\cdot)$ is continuous and hence its infimum must be attained over $\overline{B_\alpha(p)}\cap F$. So there is some $y\in F$ that get us the result.

Comment: I don't think it can be - $x$ should be in $\overline{B_\alpha(p)}$ shouldn't it?

Comment: Ah meant to say $x\in F$

Comment: Yes you right. I delete my comment. This is a good proof.

Answer (score 0):

You can see here

[A metric space such that all closed balls are compact is complete.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537593/a-metric-space-such-that-all-closed-balls-are-compact-is-complete)

that every metric space in which the balls are compact is complete.

Then construct a sequence $x_n$ in $F$ such that $d(p,x_n)-d(p,X)<\displaystyle\frac{1}{2n}$. Prove that this sequence is Cauchy.

Sorry by the mistake before!